# Doctrine: join one-to-one relation

Tags: orm, symfony1, doctrine, entity-relationship

Suppose we have two models: `Post` and `ViewsCount`. Relation type is 1:1.

Now I want to retrieve last 5 posts with their views stats:

```
$posts = PostTable::getInstance()->createQuery('p')
    ->leftJoin('p.ViewsCount') // relation name is "ViewsCount"
    ->orderBy('p.created_at DESC')
    ->limit(5)
    ->execute();
```

But, there is no luck. It throws an error. If I remove joining - everything is ok.

So, my question is - **How to automatically join/retrieve one-to-one relation in Doctrine to avoid lot's of additional queries?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in syntax. You also need to tell doctrine you want to retrieve the ViewCount fields:

```
$posts = PostTable::getInstance()->createQuery('p')
  ->select('p.*, vc.*')
  ->leftJoin('p.ViewsCount vc')
  ->orderBy('p.created_at DESC')
  ->limit(5)
  ->execute();
```

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't help. Now I get another error about hydration

Answer (score 0):

Is seems that you should define relations properly.
For each model define relations with type key (type:one).